# How do I change an attribute on a struct to a new value which contains the old value?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How do I change an attribute on a struct to a new value which contains the old value?

```
struct Container {
    more: Box<Container>
}

struct ContainerBox {
    container: Option<Container>
}

impl ContainerBox {
    pub fn ingest(&mut self, container: Container) {
        match &self.container {
            Some(container) => {
                self.container = Some(Container { more: (*container).clone() }); // this doesn't look right.
            },
            None => self.container = Some(container)
        };
    }
}
```

Very silly example but it gets the point across. I have a struct that owns some data that may be something or nothing, when its something, I need to replace it with a new instance of the same type which is composed of the old value in that structs attribute.

I think I understand why the borrow checker is unhappy, but I also can't see another way to write this.

Comment: I'm distracted by the infinity that is a `Container`. How do you make one if it always requires another `Container`?

Comment: This is a mistake on my part. I wrote this out to point out the problem I was facing in a more complex piece of code.

Comment: Hah, that's funny. Glad you got an answer from someone not as distracted as I was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take):

```rust
impl ContainerBox {
    pub fn ingest(&mut self, container: Container) {
        match self.container.take() {
            Some(container) => {
                self.container = Some(Container { more: Box::new(container) });
            },
            None => self.container = Some(container),
        };
    }
}
```